# Split and view the long sentence in multiple lines in html table

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

In my view I have to split the long sentences into multiple lines in an HTML table.
I used a code but it didn't work as I don't want to clip the sentence. I want to show the whole sentence in multiple lines.

This is the code line I used:

```
 <td class="col-md-3" style="overflow-wrap:break-word;text-overflow:clip;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Note, new { @class = "note" })</td>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap:break-word` for this

```
<td class="col-md-3" style="word-wrap:break-word;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Note, new { @class = "note" })</td>
```

> if you want to wrap big word then you can use `word-break: break-all`

```
<td class="col-md-3" style="word-break: break-all;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Note, new { @class = "note" })</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think table cell **default break** your sentence in multiple line like `word-wrap:break-word` , if you wants to `break-all` then only you can use style as suggested by @Super User.

Check my code snippet for default break line:

```html
<table style="border:1px solid #CCC;width:100%">
        <tr  id="accounting" >
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td style="word-break: break-word;">Accounting Personnel testing long line and going to split in two lines if succedd will go ahead.</td>
            <td>
                <div class="actions pull-right approvers">Div
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i>Click</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  id="hr" >
            <td class="left"><a>errrrr</a></td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>Luke</td>
            <td>HR Personnel</td>
            <td>
                <div class="actions pull-right approvers">Div
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i>Click</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr  id="crm" >
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>CRM Personnel</td>
            <td>
                <div class="actions pull-right approvers">Div
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-close" title="remove approvers"></i>Click</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your sentence to be distributed into multiple lines and don't want the words to be broken(which I assume you are looking for), use:

```
 word-break: keep-all;
```

But if you want to break the words into multiple lines when it overflows the container, use:

```
word-break: break-all;
```

**Note:** `word-break` is a **CSS3** property. So, it is not supported by all of the browsers. It's totally not supported in *Opera mini* and *IE* versions before 11. But mostly supported by the modern browsers. You can see the supported browsers [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break).

Answer (score 0):

```
<td class="col-md-3" style="word-break:break-word;text-overflow:clip;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Note, new { @class = "note" })</td>
```

This worked for me correctly.

```
<td class="col-md-3" style="word-break: break-all;">@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.Note, new { @class = "note" })</td>
```

This also useful. But it splits word also.